# I want to use zabbix6 to monitor the log files

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

1. The log files to be monitored are as follows, and I want to monitor the string "ERROR".

   ```
   /var/log/waagent.log
   ```
2. ITEM

   ```
   log[/var/log/waagent.log,,,,skip]
   ```

[image]

3. Trigger : If more than 0, trigger will occur.

   ```
   count(/Linux Azure Waagent/log[/var/log/waagent.log,,,,skip],#1,"regexp","ERROR")>0
   ```

[image]

4. Result

   It seems to be searching for "`ERROR`" throughout the log file. I want to find "`ERROR`" in the last line of the log file.

If possible, I also want to create a trigger that solves the problem when "`INFO`" is printed. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring "ERROR" in the last line of the log file:
Change the log file path to:

```
/var/log/waagent.log|tail -n 1
Modify the trigger condition to: count(/Linux Azure Waagent/log[/var/log/waagent.log|tail -n 1,,,,skip],#1,"regexp","ERROR") > 0
```

For creating a trigger for "INFO":
Add a new trigger condition:`javascriptcount(/Linux Azure Waagent/log[/var/log/waagent.log|tail -n 1,,,,skip],#1,"regexp","INFO") > 0`